# Getting UIWebview api deprecation message after adding PayPal pod in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, cocoapods, app-store-connect

I was building an iOS app and on a specific build version I added PayPal pod. Then when I submitted that app for test-flight, I got a **UIWebview API Deprecation message**

> ITMS - 90809

I am using pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK' for paypal integration

So what can I do to resolve this, and will it create any problem for successful app submission?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using a deprecated PayPal mobile SDK that is no longer supported for new integrations

If you need a native SDK, [PayPal Express Checkout via the Braintree Mobile SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/) is supported

Comment: the reason for getting the message is the paypal pod.. so i was wondering that if i can edit the pod or is it possible to edit paypal pod? cause it's written on objective c and i am using swift..

Comment: I would contact the paypal pod folks.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the PayPal Website, they were saying to Use Xcode 7+ and iOS 9+ Base SDK.

In Apple documents https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview you can see that, its deprecated with iOS 12.

So Intimate them about this.
With the documentation of Paypal in the see also area there is a link to https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/tree/master/BraintreePayPal. While checking its showing recently updated, please check the same and try to integrate it.